# How to return only one instance of a command in SQL 2008r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What I am attempted to do is only return the columns in the query below where the first dispatch time (`inmain.firstdtm`) and associated time stamp in the incident radio log match (`incilog.timestamp`) for the code representing a unit being `dispatched('D')`.
The problem is the timestamp filed is logging to the nanosecond and the firstdtm field is not.

So in the where statement how can I get it to just compare the timedate fileds only to the second?

```
SELECT DISTINCT inmain.inci_id, inmain.calltime, inmain.firstdtm, incilog.timestamp, incilog.userid, inmain.secs2fn, inmain.secs2di,
                inmain.calltaker, inmain.street

FROM incilog INNER JOIN
                         inmain ON incilog.inci_id = inmain.inci_id

WHERE   (inmain.calltime>= dateadd(day,datediff(day,30,GETDATE()),0)
        AND inmain.calltime< dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)) AND (inmain.agency= 'UEMS') 
        AND (incilog.transtype='D') AND (inmain.firstdtm=???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `incilog.timestamp`field is a datetime/datetime2 for example you could remove the millisecond part by subtracting it using dateadd like this example:

```
declare @ts datetime
set @ts = getdate()
select @ts ts, dateadd(MILLISECOND, -datepart(MILLISECOND, @ts),@ts) ts_no_ms

ts                      ts_no_ms
----------------------- -----------------------
2014-11-14 01:47:42.663 2014-11-14 01:47:42.000
```

Using this logic you could do something like below in your where clause:

```
WHERE (inmain.firstdtm = dateadd(MILLISECOND, -datepart(MILLISECOND, incilog.timestamp),incilog.timestamp)
```

Comment: @GarySilsby If my answer helped solve your problem you should consider accepting it - there's no obligation to do so though.

Comment: @GarySilsby I guess you figured it out :)